# Regex as Lua pattern

Tags: regex, lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

I wrote `(?<=;)[^\^]*` regex but I have problem with transforming it to use it in Lua. I want to transform

```
^#57df44;Cobblestone^white;
```

into

```
Cobblestone
```

but if the string does not contain any color code then it should be returned "as is".

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: `s = s:gsub("^.-;(.-)^.*$", "%1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capturing group:

```
local s = "^#57df44;Cobblestone^white;"
res = s:match(";([^^]*)") or s
print( res )
-- Cobblestone
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/RlUA3A).

Here,

- `;` - matches the first `;`
- `([^^]*)` - Capturing group 1 matches any 0+ chars other than `^` into Group 1

The `string.match` will only return the captured part if the capturing group is defined in the pattern.

**More details**

As is mentioned in comments, you might use a [*frontier pattern*](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FrontierPattern) `%f[^:]` instead of `(?<=:)` in the current scenario.

> The frontier pattern %f followed by a set detects the transition from "not in set" to "in set".

However, the frontier pattern is not a good substitute for a positive lookbehind `(?<=:)` because the latter can deal with *sequences* of patterns, while a frontier pattern only works with single atoms. So, `%f[^:]` means *place in string between `:` and a non-`:`*. Howerver, once you need to match any 0+ chars other than `^` after `city=`, a frontier pattern would be a wrong construct to use. So, it is not that easily scalable as a `string.match` with a capturing group.

Comment: Here is a [demo for multiple occurrences](https://ideone.com/PM5AMF). But I suspect only the first match is what is necessary, so `string.match` is what you need.

Comment: It mostly works, but it fails if text has no color codes (returns nil). This minor issue can be however fixed with simple or.
`s:match(";([^^]*)") or s;`

Comment: @user2463506 Sorry, I overlooked that part of the question. Yes, looks like that will do. I added the `or` bit to the answer.

Comment: string.match(s, '%f[^;]([^^]*)')

Comment: @moteus - You can omit parentheses: `s:match"%f[^;][^^]*"`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That frontier pattern is not really that necessary in this case. A capturing group is enough, more readable, mor euniversal (what if the `;` context should be precised and becomes a multicharacter string?) and easy to understand. The lookbehind `(?<=;)` construct can deal with *sequences*, the frontier pattern can't.

Comment: @user2463506: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since you reached 15 rep points and now are entitled to upvoting.